# friends, I wanted to add JavaScript object property name by using 2 variable / dynamic value and I wanted to call it dynamically

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
let name = "asraf";
var a = "hello";
var Obj = {
  [a+name] : "Asraful islam ",//it's working 
  course : "Btec",
  detail : function (){
    return this.a+name+ " is a student of " + this.course; // it's didn't working 
  }
}
console.log(Obj.detail());
```

**output : undefinedasraf is a student of Btec**

Comment: The [a+name] is not allowed!!

Comment: @HangoverSoundSound, sure it is. Did you try?

Comment: Use the same syntax as you did to define the property: `return this[a+name]`

Comment: Very strange that this question was closed. Shorif, remove ``this.`` from ``this.a`` so its just ``a``, and you should not have any more problems.

Comment: @Kenny.Harrer, it is not strange that it was closed, since this has been asked many times before in different ways. And what you propose will just print the value of `a`, not the property in the object, which is what the Asker wants.

Comment: @Kenny.Harrer, I provided help above. Did you read my comment? And yes, this is duplicate. But still I provided the way out in comments. How is that not helping?

Comment: @trincot When I wrote my comment you had not commented yet. It's a misunderstanding.